# 2d array causing run time error

Tags: c++, arrays

Here is my code, strangely excerpt of it is working fine. However, the main program is having run time error due to this array ss.

```
#define FOR(i,n) for(i=0;i<n;i++)
unordered_map<int,int>m;
```

........

```
int ss[1000][1000]={0};

        FOR(i,n){
            FOR(j,n){
                if( (i+1 < n) && A[i][j]==A[i+1][j]+1 )
                {
                    if(ss[i][j]==-1)ss[i+1][j]=A[i][j];
                    else ss[i+1][j]=ss[i][j];m[ss[i+1][j]]++;
                }
                if((j+1 < n) && A[i][j]==A[i][j+1]+1)
                {if(ss[i][j]==-1)ss[i][j+1]=A[i][j];
                else ss[i][j+1]=ss[i][j];m[ss[i][j+1]]++;
                }
```

When i try to increment its value in m, it causes the run time error.

Comment: can you share your error and if possible all of your code

Comment: It simply says run time error!

Comment: What is A ?  Same size as ss?

Comment: Are you entering an obfuscated code competition? That `FOR` macro is, IMO, an abomination, and you're completely hiding your modifications to `m` in line noise. Use spaces and newlines, they're cheap.

Comment: If the size of `int` is 4, `ss` will require about 4 MB of memory. That might be too much stack memory for your platform. Use heap memory to get around the problem. Try `std::vector<std::vector<int>> ss(1000, std::vector<int>(1000, 0));` instead.

Comment: Add print statements inside the `for` loops and identify the line which causes the run time error and identify the value of `i` and `j` at that time. Since your bound checks looks ok, my first suspect would be array `m` since it does not use `i` or `j` for indexing, instead uses value present in `ss`.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks for your comment...that was the exact problem...In a lot of all people, you were able to figure out the issue! FOR is indeed not a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform, `ss` will require about 4 MB of memory. That might be too much stack memory for your platform. Use heap memory to get around the problem.

Try

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> ss(1000, std::vector<int>(1000, 0));
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

i think you must define integer variable "i and j" before **FOR(i,n)**;

try this one:

```
int ss[1000][1000]={0};
    int i,j;
    FOR(i,n){
        FOR(j,n){
            if( (i+1 < n) && A[i][j]==A[i+1][j]+1 )
            {
                if(ss[i][j]==-1)ss[i+1][j]=A[i][j];
                else ss[i+1][j]=ss[i][j];m[ss[i+1][j]]++;
            }
            if((j+1 < n) && A[i][j]==A[i][j+1]+1)
            {if(ss[i][j]==-1)ss[i][j+1]=A[i][j];
            else ss[i][j+1]=ss[i][j];m[ss[i][j+1]]++;
            }
```

Comment: If `i` and `j`, are not defined, there will be compile time errors. It doesn't explain the run time error.